# Prove $A \cup (\cap B)=\cap\{A\cup b: b \in B\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition** The amalgamated intersection of $A$ is defined by $\cap A=\{x \mid \forall a \in A, x \in a \}$

Prove $A \cup (\cap B)=\cap\{A\cup b: b \in B\}$

Let $x \in \cap\{A \cup b: b \in B\}$, then $\forall a, a \in A\cup b , x\in a$ then $\forall a, a \in A $ $\vee$  $a \in b $ then $\forall a, a \in A, x \in a $ $\vee$ $\forall a, a \in b, x \in a$ then $x \in A$ $\vee$ $\forall a \in B, x \in a $ this is beacuase $a \in b \wedge b \in B \Rightarrow a \in B$ and $x \in a \wedge a \in A \Rightarrow x \in A$; then $x \in A \cup (\cap B)$

I don't know if what I did is correct and to prove $\subset$ I need help. Could you help me? Please.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but if $\cap A = \{x\mid\forall a \in A, x\in A\}$, then $\cap A = A$?. Clearly if $z\in A$, then $z \in \cap A$ and if $z\in\cap A$, then $z\in A$ by condition, so their are teh same set: $A = \cap A$

Comment: I corrected my mistake, sorry

Comment: So the elements of $A$ are sets, right?

Comment: We can think that

Comment: its very weird and I don't see any intuiton hint, The only approach on my mind who solves the problem is work by cases. First case $z \in A$, second case $z \notin A$.

Comment: You've misinterpreted $$x \in \cap\{A \cup b: b \in B\}$$ in the first line.  It means $\forall b \in B, x \in A\cup b$.  Your interpretation would be for $x \in \cap(A \cup b)$

Answer (score 1):

What you write as $\cap\{A\cup b:b\in B\}$, I suspect you mean $\{x:\forall b\in B~.x\in A\cup b\}$, or simply $\bigcap_{b\in B} (A\cup b)$

(Similarly $\bigcap B$ appears to be a shorthand for ${\bigcap}_{b\in B} b$, which is $\{x:\forall b\in B~.x\in b\}$ )

Thus you seek to prove:
$$\begin{align}A\cup \bigcap B &= \{x: x\in A\lor x\in\bigcap B\} \\[1ex] &=\{x:x\in A\lor (\forall b\in B~.x\in b)\}\\[1ex]&=\{x:\forall b\in B~.(x\in A\lor x\in b)\}\\[1ex]&=\{x:\forall b\in B~.x\in (A\cup b)\}\\[1ex]&={\bigcap}_{b\in B}(A\cup b)\end{align}$$

---

> Let $x \in \cap\{A \cup b: b \in B\}$, then $\forall a, a \in A\cup b , x\in a$ then $\forall a, a \in A $ $\vee$  $a \in b $ then $\forall a, a \in A, x \in a $ $\vee$ $\forall a, a \in b, x \in a$ then $x \in A$ $\vee$ $\forall a \in B, x \in a $ this is beacuase $a \in b \wedge b \in B \Rightarrow a \in B$ and $x \in a \wedge a \in A \Rightarrow x \in A$; then $x \in A \cup (\cap B)$

No, $x\in a\wedge a\in A$ does not imply $x\in A$.   Moreover you are confusing your $a$, $b$, and $x$ elements.   We just need $x$ and $b$ — the arbitrary $x$ is assumed to be in the thing, and we discuss all $b$ that are in $B$.

- Take an arbitrary $x$ with the assumption that $x\in \bigcap_{b\in B}(A\cap b)$. That is to say: $\forall b\in B~.(x\in A\cup b)$. Therefore either $x\in A$ or if otherwise *you can show* $\forall b\in B~.(x\in b)$.   Hence $x\in A\cup\bigcap B$.

Thereby proving : $\bigcap_{b\in B}(A\cup b)\subseteq A\cup\bigcap B$.

---

The converse may be proven through a proof by cases.

- Take an arbitrary $x$ with the assumption that $x\in A\cup\bigcap B$. That is to say: $x\in A$ or $x\in \bigcap B$.

  - In the case of $x\in A$, there *you can show:* $\forall b\in B~.x\in (A\cup b)$.
  - In the case of $x\in \bigcap B$ [that is to say $\forall b\in B~.x\in b$], there *you can show:* $\forall b\in B~.x\in (A\cup b)$.
- Therefore $\forall b\in B~.x\in (A\cup b)$ which is to say: $x\in\bigcap_{b\in B}(A\cup b)$

Thereby proving : $\bigcap_{b\in B}(A\cup b)\supseteq A\cup\bigcap B$.

---

Together proving: $\bigcap_{b\in B}(A\cup b) = A\cup\bigcap B$.

$\blacksquare$